# How can I add a marmoset library smart material on top of a baked normal map and then export textures?

Tags: rendering, texture-mapping, normals, pbr

How can I add a marmoset library smart material on top of a baked normal map and then export textures?

I have a low poly object with a baked normal map. The bake only consists of the edge bevel data. I want to add a smart material on top of the normal map so I can have the beveled edges and material details. How can I do it?

After that I want to export the material so I can use in Unreal, the normal map essentially needs to be the combination of marmoset material normal map and my beveled edge normal map.